How do I create heatmap from csv file when csv file has multiple tables?
I am trying to convert readings from an IR sensor into a heatmap in python. I have converted the readings into a csv file using Arduino. The csv file contains multiple "tables" of values sorted into 24 rows and 32 columns please see screenshot
Is there a way that I can create individual heatmaps for each reading in the csv file? There are 15 readings in total in the file.
My initial approach was to convert the readings into a 24x32 array and plot the heatmap that way but for some reason the value in the file are of dtype <U191 and I'm unable to convert them to float. Here's what I tried.
import numpy as np
import csv

with open("serial_data.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=','))
    reading1 = reader[2:26]
    reading1_array = np.array(reading1)
    map(lambda x: float(x),reading1_array)
    print(reading1_array)

reading1_array.dtype
new_arr = reading1_array.astype(float)
print(new_arr)

Then I get an error saying ValueError: could not convert string to float: '24.0, 24.0, 24.6, 24.1, 23.1, 22.6, 22.5, 22.6, 22.7, 22.5, 22.7, 22.7, 22.9, 22.8, 23.2, 22.8, 23.2, 23.0, 23.1, 23.0, 23.1, 22.9, 23.4, 25.1, 24.3, 27.8, 26.0, 28.0, 26.4, 26.2, 25.5, 25.3,'

check how to read csv files https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html.
what are try to convert in to list ?

the file is NOT a CSV file, you have to write a custom parser yourself, you can use the re module and the functions re.findall or re.finditer

if file contains multiple "tables"  then it is NOT valid csv. You may have to read it as normal text, split every table to separated string and later parse it with csv

you have Ambient ... = in file and it is NOT allowed in csv. Besides you have every line in "" so csv treats every line as single text. You may have to split it manually, and convert every element to float(). Maybe better change code on Arduino and write it as correct files CSV

Please don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.

If file contains multiple "tables" then it is NOT valid csv.
You have Ambient ... = in file and it is NOT allowed in csv.
Besides you have every line in "" so csv treats every line as single text.
You may have to read it as normal text, split it manually, split every line to list of strings with numbers, and convert every row to float().
Maybe better change code on Arduino and write it as correct files CSV.

Minimal working example.
I use io.StringIO to simulate file - so everyone can simply copy and run it.

I get firs element for every row - [0]
I remove spaces and , at the end of line - .rstrip(' ,')
I split line to list of strings (with numbers) - .split(', ')
I convert strings to floats - map(float, row)

That's all.
text = '''Ambient temperature = 
""
"24.0, 24.0, 24.6, 24.1, 23.1, 22.6, 22.5, 22.6, 22.7, 22.5, 22.7, 22.7, 22.9, 22.8, 23.2, 22.8, 23.2, 23.0, 23.1, 23.0, 23.1, 22.9, 23.4, 25.1, 24.3, 27.8, 26.0, 28.0, 26.4, 26.2, 25.5, 25.3,"
"24.0, 24.0, 24.6, 24.1, 23.1, 22.6, 22.5, 22.6, 22.7, 22.5, 22.7, 22.7, 22.9, 22.8, 23.2, 22.8, 23.2, 23.0, 23.1, 23.0, 23.1, 22.9, 23.4, 25.1, 24.3, 27.8, 26.0, 28.0, 26.4, 26.2, 25.5, 25.3,"
'''

import csv
import io
import numpy as np

#with open("serial_data.csv", "r") as file:
with io.StringIO(text) as file:
    all_data = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=','))
    #print(all_data)

    data = all_data[2:26]
    
    data = [row[0].strip(' ,')    for row in data]  # strip some chars from lines
    data = [row.split(', ')       for row in data]  # split string to list of strings
    data = [list(map(float, row)) for row in data]  # convert every row to float values

print('rows:')
for row in data:
    print(row)

array = np.array(data)

print('array:')
print(array)

Result:
rows:
[24.0, 24.0, 24.6, 24.1, 23.1, 22.6, 22.5, 22.6, 22.7, 22.5, 22.7, 22.7, 22.9, 22.8, 23.2, 22.8, 23.2, 23.0, 23.1, 23.0, 23.1, 22.9, 23.4, 25.1, 24.3, 27.8, 26.0, 28.0, 26.4, 26.2, 25.5, 25.3]
[24.0, 24.0, 24.6, 24.1, 23.1, 22.6, 22.5, 22.6, 22.7, 22.5, 22.7, 22.7, 22.9, 22.8, 23.2, 22.8, 23.2, 23.0, 23.1, 23.0, 23.1, 22.9, 23.4, 25.1, 24.3, 27.8, 26.0, 28.0, 26.4, 26.2, 25.5, 25.3]

array:
[[24.  24.  24.6 24.1 23.1 22.6 22.5 22.6 22.7 22.5 22.7 22.7 22.9 22.8
  23.2 22.8 23.2 23.  23.1 23.  23.1 22.9 23.4 25.1 24.3 27.8 26.  28.
  26.4 26.2 25.5 25.3]
 [24.  24.  24.6 24.1 23.1 22.6 22.5 22.6 22.7 22.5 22.7 22.7 22.9 22.8
  23.2 22.8 23.2 23.  23.1 23.  23.1 22.9 23.4 25.1 24.3 27.8 26.  28.
  26.4 26.2 25.5 25.3]]


EDIT:
The same without module csv - it has to strip extra chars "\n. And doesn't use [0]
#with open("serial_data.csv", "r") as file:
with io.StringIO(text) as file:
    all_data = list(file)
    #print(all_data)

    data = all_data[2:26]

    data = [row.strip('"\n ,')    for row in data]  # strip some chars from lines
    data = [row.split(', ')       for row in data]  # split string to list of strings
    data = [list(map(float, row)) for row in data]  # convert every row to float values

